# for loop in javascript, with increment operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

this creates an infinite loop

```
for (i=0;++i;){      
  console.log(i)
}
```

this one doesn't even executed why

```
for (i=0;i++;){      
  console.log(i)
}
```

want to understand it completely in depth

Comment: Completely in depth? Try a book or your favourite online tutorial. They will tell you how to use the basic form of for-loop.

Comment: see the docs on for loops The incrementor is the **third** statement in the loops header ... The second is the condition. Furthermore read about *pre* and *post* increment operators. In the first case `++i` will always return a positive number, which is a truthy, and therefore continues the loop. In the second case `i++` will return `0` and thus, your loop won't iterate even once ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anatomy of for loop:

```
for(/* runs first before the loop */;
/* runs before every iteration, if this one is falsy, the loop breaks */;
/* runs after every iteraion */)
```

```
i++ // returns the current value of i and then increments the value
++i // first increments the value then returns
```

First loop:

```
let i = 0; // i is 0
let continueCondition = ++i; // continueCondition and i are 1
```

Every positive value is truthy so the loop continues forever

Second loop:

```
let i = 0; // i is 0
let continueCondition = i++; // continueCondition is 0 but i is 1
```

`0` is falsy so the loop breaks before it starts

Comment: `x` may be confusing, let me edit

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, it is because you didn't set the rule when to stop, aka condition.

```
for (let step = 0; step < 5; step++) {
  // Runs 5 times, with values of step 0 through 4.
  console.log('Walking east one step');
}
```

Here is code that has to run properly.
Also, please edit your question for clarity

```
for (before loop; if true => make an iteration; after iteration)
```

This has to be the proper model of the loop. It has to have condition, while first and last piece, may be missing

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Both loops in the question are correct. Why is the first an infinite loop and the second doesn't start?